# My AngularJS validation does not work. I have added ng-required

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

My AngularJS validation does not work. I have added ng-required. Please let me know where I am missing

```
<ng-form id="frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
                <button id="cm-SaveBtn" name="cm-SaveBtn" type="button" ng-click="submitted=true">Save</button>
                <button id="cm-RefreshBtn" name="cm-RefreshBtn" type="button">Refresh</button>
            </div>
          <div>
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="VNAVLabel">Process Begin Date: </span></td>
                            <td> 
                                <span><input type="date" name="processBeginDate" ng-model="processBeginDate" required></span>
                                <span ng-show="(frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$dirty || submitted) && frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required">
                                    Process Begin Date is required
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

</ng-form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be `id`, you should use `name` attribute instead. Angular will create `$scope` variable with name `frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance` which will contain form information.

```
<ng-form name="frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 'name' instead of 'id' for the form element.

Also, you do not have to check for `(frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$dirty || submitted)` only `frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required` would do the job.

```
<ng-form name="frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance">
   <div style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
      <button id="cm-SaveBtn" name="cm-SaveBtn" type="button" ng-click="submitted=true">Save</button>
      <button id="cm-RefreshBtn" name="cm-RefreshBtn" type="button">Refresh</button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><span class="VNAVLabel">Process Begin Date: </span></td>
            <td> 
               <span><input type="date" name="processBeginDate" ng-model="processBeginDate" required></span>
               <span ng-show="frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required">
               Process Begin Date is required
               </span>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank You!

Comment: But I only want to display the error on save button click not on page load @Sachet Gupta. How can I do that

Comment: in this case use `ng-required="submitted"` . This will execute the required validation to run when the condition is true. so in this will validate for required field when save is clicked and once you start typing it will remove the message because `frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required` . Quick [Plnkr  example here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dF2qbyiRPcEVAy91mnr?p=preview)